# Проблема с хэндлером

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Пишу хэндлер для бота, хочу реализовать так, чтобы бот генерировал случайные пароли, создавал (в путь который я указал) `txt` с паролями и отправлял их файлом `txt` (документом), но не из БД, а из пути, который я указал у себя на компе, хочу посмотреть как это работает и работает ли это. Пока что я только учусь их писать, мне нужна помощь, в интернете ничего найти подобного не смог. Запустить и проверить хэндлер на работоспособность пока что нет, т.к. я не дома и не имею возможности его протестировать код в данный момент, может быть вам сразу в глаза что нибудь бросится.

```
import random
import string
from aiogram.types import InputFile
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

class GeneratePass(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_length = State()
    waiting_for_amount = State()


async def random_char(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
                   for _ in range(length))

async def generate_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Укажите длинну пароля цифрами: ")
    await state.set_state(GeneratePass.waiting_for_length.state)


async def generate_length(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not message.text.isdigit() and 0 < message.text <= 10:
        await message.answer("Пожалуйста введите длину пароля цифрами и не более 10")
        return
    await state.update_data(pass_length=message.text)

    await state.set_state(GeneratePass.waiting_for_amount.state)
    await message.answer('Теперь укажи колличество паролей для генерации')

async def generate_amount(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not message.text.isdigit() and 0 < message.text <= 10:
        await message.answer("Введите количество сгенерированных паролей не более 10")
        return
    await state.update_data(pass_amount=message.text)

    rpass = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f'Генерация с длинной {rpass['pass_length']}, кол-во {rpass['pass_amount']}
    
    file_path = 'D:/tmp/password.txt'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        for passwd in range(rpass['pass_amount']):
                password = random_char(rpass['pass_length'])
                    f.write(password + '\n')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await message.answer_document(open(file_path, 'rb'))
    # или
    await message.answer_document(InputFile(file_path))
```

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: Кавычка незакрытая бросается) И f-строка тоже у тебя будет ошибку бить

Comment: Все спасибо вам, мне просто нужен был ответ от вас, так как я не мог проверить скрипт сам, в силу некоторых обстоятельств